# Regex for dot and digit validation

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate dot and numbers.

**Valid:**

```
1.2.3
1.4.1
```

**Invalid:**

```
1.2.3.
1.2-3
1-2-3
```

I tried the following from another thread, it works with the valid, but it also passes the invalid with dash (-).

```
^\d+(.\d+)*$
```

Any betterment to the regex so it strict to validate only dot and digit?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the dot, which is otherwise "any character" in a regex:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)*$
```

Answer (score 3):

Ttry this:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)*$
```

**[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?328gg)**

Answer (score 2):

If you need a variable number of dots and digits repeat digits & dots and put the last as only digit:

```
(\d+\.)+\d+
```

it matches 1.2.3 1.2.3.4 and so on

If you need fixed length of digits put the number of repetitions instead of the + operator

```
(\d+\.){2}\d+ #for 1.2.3
(\d+\.){1}\d+ #for 1.2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it. Good lesson.

Answer (score 1):

use this regular expression `^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$`

your misstake in dot, dot mean any symbol

Answer (score 1):

The dot matches all characters, you should use \.

^\d+(\.\d+)*$

But this would also validate any number without dot, when at least 1 dot should be present use:

(\d+\.)+\d+